# How to log events in java when the code is extremely recursive ( for example a multi-children tree)

Tags: java

I am asked to write logs in an effective way to a product that is related to parsing CSV files. Now, this code is enormous and extremely recursive. I saw that it creates a lot of clutter if I try to log in directly(as in log the states inside recursive loops) and hence is very hard to later analyze the log files during a failure or malfunction. Any help on how to write logs here in an effective manner will be very helpful.

The code is more about parsers and building several trees at each phase. Now, these trees are built in a recursive manner and writing logs here(inside such recursive loops) will log in a manner very hard to understand and analyze. So can it be done in a way so that it can be understood better (maybe a visual representation of the code in the log would help)

Comment: What does "extremely recursive" mean? What is the alternative to "if I try to log it directly"? I don't think anyone can help you with this question.

Comment: Show us what you tried so far? Meanwhile go-through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @miiiii That's a huge codebase.. So I donno how to show u the code

Comment: Show at least the sudo-code of that part where you want to put logging.

Comment: @f1sh Extremely recursive code meaning, for example, constructing a huge multi-children tree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know what you want to have as result of logging. It does not matter recursive you code or not if you log something then you will have it in you logs.

So, if you really have to log event inside the cycle then I guess, may be you want to split significant events and not.

For example (use slf4j and logback):
Log events normal way.

```
    LOGGER.trace("log message");
```

Log significant things with info level and upper and all other things with trace then add two appenders with different log levels.
logback.xml:

```
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>@project.artifactId@.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>INFO</level>
        </filter>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%-8level %-25d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

   <appender name="FILE_TRACE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>@project.artifactId@_trace.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%-8level %-25d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE_TRACE" />
    </root>
```

In this case one log file will have everything and the second one only significant data (errors, warnings and info).

So, it will be easier to monitoring significant things using file with INFO level and you will have full log in file with TRACE level.